# How long to install Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation

Clean install, replacing Windows 7, from a USB stick.  (Windows boot sector was messed up, but no hard disk or memory errors.)  I'm installing 32-bit Ubuntu on my 64-bit machine, because the 64-bit version (labeled for AMD--I have Intel) would not run from the stick.  Quad-core, 6 gb memory. Connecting wirelessly to fiber.  Using a stick because the computer I used to download Ubuntu won't write DVDs.

So far it's taken more than three hours, which is way more than previous posts have suggested.  The progress line is about 1/4 of the way across and the text says it's copying files.  I asked for updates to be downloaded.  No error messages.  The progress line is moving--not visibly, but I put some tape on it to check and got a few more millimeters in last 20 minutes.

Has something gone wrong, or is this just a slow server for updates?

Update:  After 5 hrs it's half way.  I'll leave it overnight.
Hardware info:  HP Pavilion dv6 laptop, quadcore, 64 bit.

Comment: The x64 extension was made by AMD thus why AMD64 is the name if the x64 file all recent Intel chips implement the x86 AMD64 extension.  If it didn't boot there is another reason and it should take 2 hours at most. Let's start with specific hardware information

Answer (score 0):

The original X64 specification was created by AMD ,and hence the name amd64. It has been implemented by AMD, Intel, VIA, and others.So you can try amd64 Ubuntu image in your Intel system.

I hope the installation doesn't froze since you noticed changes in the progress bar.This can be caused by slow downloads.

First, try installing  the ubuntu without downloading the updates to be sure this problem is caused by slow downloads.If you are successful at installing the system you may consider upgrading it following this article [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade)